# Why can't I close my kendo window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I have this kendo window on my page:

```
<kendo-button ng-click="modalEnquiryText.center().open();" value="Open" class="k-button">
    Enquiry Text
</kendo-button>

<div kendo-window="modalEnquiryText" k-width="1000" k-height="380" k-visible="false" k-title="'Enquiry Text Viewer'">

    <div class="col-md-12">

        <div class="k-content">
            <ul kendo-panel-bar k-options="panelBarOptions">
                <li class="k-state-active">
                    Current Sticky Notes
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <textarea id="EnquiryTextEditor" kendo-editor k-ng-model="FormattedEnquiryText"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="pull-right">
        <kendo-button ng-click="modalenquirytext.center().close(); bindHtml()" value="Close" class="k-button k-primary">
            Add Enquiry Text
        </kendo-button>

        <kendo-button  ng-click="closeModal(); modalEnquiryText.center().close()" value="Cancel" class="k-button">
            Discard and Close Window
        </kendo-button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried using ng-click with two functions and that doesn't work, and I tried using jQuery to select the window div and close it with this code:

```
$scope.bindHtml = function() {
                        $scope.enquiryText = strip($scope.FormattedEnquiryText);
                        //reset values on close
                        $("#EnquiryTextEditor").data("kendoEditor").value("");
                        commmonUtilities.addAlert('Enquiry Text Added', 'success');

                       $("#modalEnquiryText").data("kendoWindow").close();

                        //$("#modalEnquiryText").data("kendoWindow").close();
                    };
```

.close(); is an undefined function.

Does anyone know what I need to change? I am using angularJs with kendo ui.

Comment: I was doing it wrong by not having an ID on the window and using the kendo window name instead. If anyone knows a nice angular way of doing this please let me know.

Comment: Check HTML on the page. Is kendo-window="modalEnquiryText" adding an id? Try also to add id="modalEnquiryText" to your div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an name to a Kendo widget in Angular (`kendo-window="modalEnquiryText"`) makes the widget object accessible through the scope/controller - so in your case, you can use `$scope.modalEnquiryText.close()` in a ng-click function. Something along these lines will probably work:

```
$scope.bindHtml = function() {
  $scope.enquiryText = strip($scope.FormattedEnquiryText);
  $scope.FormattedEnquiryText = ""; // Don't use jQuery here either! Angular bindings are two-way.
  commmonUtilities.addAlert('Enquiry Text Added', 'success');
  $scope.modalEnquiryText.close();
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, that worked. I couldn't find anywhere in the documentation that says that's how to close a window in angular :(

Comment: Yep, I've been there! The documentation for Kendo's Angular integration is pretty much non-existent...